# Do time boundaries apply to a handicap parking sign?

Tags: local-ordinance

[image]

Given the sign above here is the scenario: street parking space, no indicating blue or otherwise markings on the street, it's 7pm, and I'm not handicapped, can I park here?

In other words should this be read: "handicapped parking and 90min parking from 6a-6p..." OR could it reasonably be read "from 6a-6p this is handicapped and 90min parking"

And other than the "you're healthy can't you just park elsewhere?" And "I wouldn't risk parking there" (most people I ask are in the latter) I'm interested if anyone has any more official experience with this that they can point to. Not necessarily looking for a specific city, but I did see this in Kalamazoo, Mi.

Also I'm not trying to fight a ticket or anything but saw this sign and my college logic classes started kicking in...

Thanks for easing my curiosity!

Comment: I am not comfortable rendering an opinion, at least without more context than the sign itself (e.g. is a handicap emblem present on the ground, what is the sign next to, etc.). I honestly find it to be a confusing sign.

Comment: What's the municipality? The parking ordinance is surely relevant.

Comment: It entirely depends on the wording of the law that allows whoever put the sign up to impose parking restrictions in the first place. Without knowing where the sign is we have no idea. Answers may be different between England, New South Wales and Philladelphia, Pa.

Comment: @ohwilleke there were no other indication that the spot was handicapped via markings or otherwise and no line distinguishing it from the other five spots in front of it. It was just streetside parking with nothing else around the sign. Thanks!

Comment: @phoog sorry I didn't make it clearer but I saw this in Kalamazoo, Michigan USA. Thanks!

Comment: @DaleM the sign was in Kalamazoo, Michigan USA. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this as a separate answer due to the length. user6726 is correct, according to the City of Kalamazoo. I reached out to Kalamazoo's information line and received the following information from them:

> Please excuse this late reply. Here is some information about the parking restrictions depicted in your photograph that I hope clears up any confusion:
>
> The Disabled Persons sign (left) is only for disabled persons to park
>   at- but the restrictions for disabled persons is 90 minute max parking
>   6a-6p expect on Sundays and Holidays. The city wide parking
>   restriction from 2a-6a is still in effect unless signed otherwise,
>   which it is not here. So any disabled person can park left of the sign
>   6a-6p for max 90 minutes Monday – Saturday unless on a holiday, and
>   from 6p-2a with no max time limit until 2a. On Sundays and holidays,
>   any disabled person can park there with no time limits from 6a-2a the
>   following morning (Monday).
>
> Anyone can park to the right of the sign with the same time and day restrictions note d above.
>
> The Disabled
>   Persons sign indicates that only a [disabled person](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(2lhgufyv4raoyzhu4o1jrv1e))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-257-19a&query=on&highlight=disabled) can park there and
>   within those, or any, restrictions and the 2a-6a restriction. The time
>   restrictions do not remove the disabled persons restriction.   I hope
>   this is helpful.
>
> If there is anything else I can help with please let me know.

Comment: I appreciate you actually reaching out to the city! Their answer does make sense and I figured as much. The sign will still forever bug me. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Michigan state law applies in this instance, with [MCL 257.674](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(pi2xzxf0wnrdbrmr3h2hvmf0))/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-257-674) being the applicable law. This section states where a vehicle may not be parked (setting aside the exceptions for "when directed by law enforcement" and "to avoid conflict with traffic"). Specifically, you may not park

> (s) In a parking space clearly identified by an official sign as being
>   reserved for use by disabled persons that is on public property or
>   private property available for public use, unless the individual is a
>   disabled person as described in section 19a or unless the individual
>   is parking the vehicle for the benefit of a disabled person.

A street is public property, thus this is a location governed by that law (even if it is private property available for public use, the law applies). Time and manner of parking ("back-in only") are addressed in that section as well:

> (w) In violation of an official sign restricting the period of time
>   for or manner of parking.

We can conclude, from appearances, that this is an official sign. The wording of the sign does not matter all that much, what matters is the state law. The law states 27 prohibitions: if any of those conditions is true, you may not park there. Therefore, if a spot is clearly labeled as handicapped parking, then you may not park there without suitable permit. If a spot restricts the time, e.g. 90 minutes between 6 am and 6 pm except Sundays and holidays, then you cannot park there longer than that, during those hours. No provision of the law relates time-limits on parking to the requirement for a handicapped parking permit. So the correct interpretation is that nobody may park in either space for more than 90 minutes in restricted hours, and the space on the left requires a handicapped parking permit.

[Kalamazoo traffic code](http://ecode360.com/9698604) (19) says essentially the same thing:

> In a parking space reserved for a handicapped person unless the person
>   parking the vehicle is a handicapped person as so defined or is
>   parking the vehicle for the benefit of such a person.

I am not aware of any case taken to the Supreme Court which tests this regarding traffic and parking signs, but as a general rule, unclear / confusing traffic signs do not absolve a person from the obligation to comply with the law (ignorance of the law is never an excuse).

Comment: "The wording of the sign does not matter all that much" - This is nonsense. It *does* matter. From 6pm - 6am, it is not reserved as handicap parking and (s) is false, because during that time it is no longer "identified ... as being reserved for use by disabled persons" due to the time restriction. While the law does not explicitly say time restrictions can be applied to handicap parking, it doesn't say they can't be either. It doesn't actually say anything about timeframes whatsoever. Are you trying to claim that timeframes on all signs mean nothing because the law doesn't mention them?

Comment: At the end you say, "as a general rule, unclear / confusing traffic signs do not absolve a person from the obligation to comply with the law", but the Michigan law you cite somewhat contradicts: "In a parking space **clearly** identified by an official sign as being reserved for use by disabled persons [...]" It appears that the law states that **unclear signs are in fact unenforceable** and so the debate would boil down to whether or not the sign is clear (to which I would lean the sign is unclear, but I see your argument as reasonable too, other than that wording part already mentioned).

Answer (score -1):

Parking signs are actually a lot less confusing than people try to make them. **Everything** inside the green border is all applied simultaneously. So the timeframe applies to every piece of information on the sign. From 6am to 6pm it is a 90 minute parking spot for handicapped drivers only, with exclusions for Sundays and holidays. So if it is 7pm, you can park there for as long as you want and without a handicapped placard (assuming there's not another sign somewhere that indicates restrictions for 6pm to 6am).

I used to work security and had to explain this to people *constantly* because the parking lot I worked at had three spots that allowed business visitors to park there from 8am to 5pm for up to 15 minutes, and people always tried to claim that the 15 minute limit was the only part that was time restricted, and not the business visitor parking part.

To clarify further, if the left side were always a handicapped parking regardless of time, they wouldn't have combined the sign like this. They would have instead included a single 90 minute parling sign with a separate handicapped parking sign pointing to the left, which would indicate that all the spots were 90 minute parking from 6am to 6pm but to the left were always for handicapped drivers only.

Comment: While I agree that your analysis describes what the signs actually say, I doubt that they describe what they're intended to say, and I suspect that a car without a handicap permit will get a ticket at any time.  Whether a judge would uphold the ticket probably depends more on the parking ordinance than on the sign itself.

Comment: Government is not allowed to operate on intent. If they want to restrict things they have to do it right. If their sign says something different than what they intended, then the sign always takes precedence. I can't imagine a judge anywhere in the US validating a ticket for a non-placard vehicle being parked there at 7pm. That would be a gross miscarriage of justice that would likely result in a lawsuit against the city.

Comment: @animuson Thank You! This was along my line or reasoning, though everyone I spoke to said they wouldn't take the chance. I guess on weeknights I'll typically have an open space downtown!

Comment: @animuson can you cite any statue or case law to support the rule that "If their sign says something different than what they intended, then the sign always takes precedence."? Moreover, here it is at least arguable that the sign does NOT say what you suggest. Can you cite any rule for how an ambiguous sign should be treated?

Comment: @DavidSiegel It's not even remotely arguable. All statements on the sign are applied, always. If the city wanted it to be restricted to 90 minutes only 6am - 6pm but always a handicap parking spot, then there are infinitely clearly ways of indicating that. They could have just had a single 90-minute parking sign, and a handicap sign pointing to the left. The fact that they included the handicap part with the rest of the restrictions explicitly means the restrictions apply to that part as well. I can only guess this is near a business where they need handicap parking only during business hours.

Comment: @animuson I must firmly disagree, absent a source citation, with your personal opinion.  I rather doubt your guess. The sign as shown seems to clearly apply the 6a-6p Mon-Sat rule to the 90 minutes limit, not to the handicap restriction. Can you cite even one case or law where a contrary meaning was held, or where your "rule" that  "All statements on the sign are applied, always" is laid down?

Comment: @DavidSiegel To believe otherwise is rather absurd. And the other upvoted answer cites completely irrelevant things that don't prove the contrary either. Most judges throw out citations for violations due to unclear signs. No case law exists because no prosecutor is going to appeal decisions up to higher courts over *parking violations* of all things. Trying to enforce that this sign means the spot is *always* handicap would never stand up in any court. I could easily get that citation dropped. Your position is just as much "based on personal opinion" as mine is.

Comment: Parking to the left of the sign is always restricted to those with a disabled persons. I posted a separate answer to show the response from the City of Kalamazoo.

Answer (score -1):

I would interpret this as applying the 90 minute limit on parking only 6am-6pm, and not only Sundays or Holidays, but that the Handicap restriction applies at all times. That would be my judgment based just on the sign as pictured. The laws cited in another answer seem to support this. Can anyone cite statute or case law to the contrary?

Comment: This answer has apparently been voted down by a user with a different view, who has not cited any source to support it.

Answer (score -2):

I had this exact question, and based on the tree in the photo, think I'm at the same sign!

It is very confusing. Today is a holiday (in that governmental offices are closed and postal service suspended).

I almost drive by, thinking it's be illegal, but then fully processed the information in time to back in.

As a proofreader, I was immediately inclined to interpret it to mean that I, a person without a handicap license plate, temporary rearview mirror hanger, or other such indicator, can park here since the "exception" applies.

I hear what others are saying, see the definitions as stated, but still cannot figure out how this sign could possibly mean anything other than exactly what it says: on Sundays and Holidays, the restrictions listed on this sign do not apply.

At that point, being that this is a holiday, I need not concern myself with any restrictions listed, so park, stop worrying, and get out of the car!

I'm still worried, but I can't see how anyone could interpret this sign any other way, so I'm going to swallow my fear (I have no money to pay a ticket, but I also cannot walk very far), and get moving.

Hopefully all works out well!!